# Choosing a random row fairly on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I have a MySQL table `classifieds`, it has the following fields:

- `id` = Primary Key, autoincrement
- `title`, `desc`, ........., other fields,
- `featured` = `int(1)` (1 or 0) but can be changed to `true`/`false`,
- `featured_start(date)`, `featured_end(date)`

I want to show **just one classified** at a time on my homepage. I mean, it doesn't rotate dynamically with AJAX, but with each page refresh or reload (F5).

Could someone give me some idea about how to code a *fair* MySQL query to get one featured classified at a time? By fair, that one classified must not show too many more times than other, and of course `featured_end` must be taken into account for not showing expired classifieds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` is the classic dirt-simple way of grabbing a random row.  However, it does not scale well with lots of rows in your table - it will have to run the `RAND()` function for every single row in your table, and then order all those rows (showing you just the first).

I would recommend reading [this useful article](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/).

The tl;dr version: the best database-side solution will most likely be something like:

```
SELECT `your_table`.*
FROM `your_table`
JOIN
(
  SELECT CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `your_table`)) AS `id`
) AS `random_row` USING(`id`)
```

Seriously, give that article a read, it's the best response to your question that I think you will find.

To people who would bring up the fact that gaps in your primary key will cause inaccuracies: yes, he covers that in the post I linked.

Comment: Thanks TehShrike, great article. The only "problem" is that there're some inexistent ids in the table because classifieds can be deleted, but i'll try to arrange that

Answer (score 1):

To take `featured_end` into account add `WHERE featured_end >= CURRENT_DATE`, ie

```
SELECT * 
FROM classifieds
WHERE (featured_end >= CURRENT_DATE)AND(featured = 1)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, using the '`RAND`' function -

```
SELECT classifieds.* 
FROM classifieds
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```